# Strange 10 value gets printed when I print inputed characters by their ASCII decimal code

Tags: c, input, ascii, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int end;

    while(( end = getchar() ) != EOF ){
        printf("%d\n",end);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print the ASCII codes of characters with this code but whenever I run the code after it gets the char from me it prints its ASCII equivalent with decimal 10. For example if I run the code and pass "a", it will print 97 and 10. Why does it print 10, this happens with all other characters too.
Thank you for answers and as a followup question when I add a counter after I input a character counter's value increases by two, why does this happen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int end;
    int count=0;
    while(( end = getchar() ) != EOF ){
        printf("%d\n",end);
        count++;
        printf("counter is now %d\n",count);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're on ASCII, I *would* expect a 10 there since that's the numerical value of the newline `'\n'`

Comment: you pressed enter, right?

Comment: Complementary question: what do you want/expect it to print? `%d` means that the integer is printed out in decimal base, so e.g. `'\r'` will print 13 (that's ASCII CR, or carriage return), and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated you are printing the ASCII decimal codes for `'a'` and `'\n'` respectively, this is because, in your code, `getchar` reads all the characters in the `stdin` buffer, including the newline character which is present because you press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>.

You can avoid this by simply making it be ignored by your condition:

```
while((end = getchar()) != EOF && end != '\n'){
    printf("%d\n", end);
}
```

Disclaimer: David Ranieri added a comment with the exact same solution as I was writing my answer (which he kindly deleted) so credit to him as well.

---

Regarding your comment question and the question edit:

If you don't want the `'\n'` to interrupt your parsing cycle, you can simply place the condition inside it.

```
while((end = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(end != '\n'){ //now as '\n' is ignored, the counter increases by one
       printf("%d\n", end);
       count++; 
       printf("counter is now %d\n",count);
    }
}
```

The reason why the counter is increased by two is, again, because two characters are parsed, whatever character you input and the newline character. As you can see in the sample, if you ignore the `'\n'`, the `counter` will only increase by one, provided that you only enter one character at a time.

Comment: Thanks @anastaciu, I was lazy to write a complete answer :) better with some explanation so I delete the comment.

Comment: Thank you but how can I make the code keep getting chars, when I use that code it only gets one char and the loop finishes

Comment: "how can I make the code keep getting chars, when I use that code it only gets one char and the loop finishes" Go to onlinegdb and try it there. It works fine.

Comment: @ErinçUtkuÖztürk are you looking for a [noncanonical input processing mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html)?

Comment: Regarding your disclaimer about someones comment - The proper place for answers is in the answers section, not the comments section :)  +1

Comment: @DavidRanieri, still, credit where credit is due :)

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII, a newline is represented by the value 10.

Anytime you type a sequence of characters and press the ENTER key, you get the ASCII values for the letters/numbers/symbols you types as well as the value 10 for the newline.